# How do you convert dates/times from one time zone to another in R?

Tags: r

If I have a date like this in London time: "2009-06-03 19:30", how can I convert it to the equivalent time in the US West Coast?

Comment: Related: [Change timezone in a POSIXct object](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14141537/271616).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, convert the London time to a `POSIXct` object:

```
pb.txt <- "2009-06-03 19:30"
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz="Europe/London")
```

Then use `format` to print the date in another time zone:

```
> format(pb.date, tz="America/Los_Angeles",usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2009-06-03 11:30:00 PDT"
```

There are some tricks to finding the right time zone identifier to use. More details in this post at the Revolutions blog: [Converting time zones in R: tips, tricks and pitfalls](http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html)

Comment: Format will convert the posix object to a character.

Comment: Does this conversion takes care of Day light savings adjustments?

Comment: Yes it does do the appropriate increment/decrement if the location is in the timezone database.

Comment: Where do we find the database of "tz"s?

Comment: `as.POSIXct(format(pb.date, tz="America/Los_Angeles",usetz=TRUE))` will solve the conversion to character.

Comment: @AdamO you can find a list of them with `OlsonNames()`

Answer (score 67):

Package `lubridate` holds two functions to convert timezones. According to the help pages:

`force_tz` returns a date-time that has the same clock time as `x` in the new time zone.

```
force_tz(time, tzone = "America/Los_Angeles")
```

`with_tz` changes the time zone in which an instant is displayed. The clock time displayed for the instant changes, but the moment of time described remains the same.

```
with_tz(time, tzone = "America/Los_Angeles")
```

Comment: much cleaner than other methods.

Answer (score 60):

Use `attr()` (base R) or `lubridate::with_tz()` (tidyverse) to view the same moment of time in a different time zone.

The internal value of a POSIXct object is always in UTC (number of seconds since the beginning of 1970; see `?DateTimeClasses`, but the displayed time when printed is determined by the `tzone` attribute. So change the `tzone` attribute (via `attr()` or `lubridate::with_tz()`) to display/print the same moment of time in a different time zone.

For example:

```
pb.txt <- "2009-06-03 19:30"  
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz="Europe/London")
```

Note tzone attribute determines time zone used when displayed/printed:

```
attributes(pb.date)$tzone
[1] "Europe/London"

pb.date
[1] "2009-06-03 19:30:00 BST"
```

Note that internal value is seconds since origin in UTC, regardless of tzone attribute:

```
as.numeric(pb.date)
[1] 1244053800
```

In base R, the tzone attribute can be set/changed using `attr()`:

```
attr(pb.date, "tzone") <- "America/Los_Angeles"

pb.date  
[1] "2009-06-03 11:30:00 PDT"
```

Equivalently, use `lubridate::with_tz()` (which also uses `attr`):

```
pb.date <- lubridate::with_tz(pb.date, "America/Los_Angeles")
```

Note that display time is now local clock time in PDT:

```
pb.date  
[1] "2009-06-03 11:30:00 PDT"
```

but internal value has not changed:

```
as.numeric(pb.date)
[1] 1244053800
```

so tzone does not affect any operations, only the displayed value when printed.

Comment: Don't forget to check the link posted in the accepted answer's comments (http://blog.revolution-computing.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html). I used EST and thought this answer didn't work!

Comment: Alternatively, `attr(pb.date, "tzone") <- "America/Los_Angeles"`

Comment: @ChrisHolbrook but during daylight saving time, when we want to convert EST to UTC, it makes mistake? as it is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156836/character-posixct-conversion-in-r-causes-wrong-timezone-values-on-daylight-savin?noredirect=1&lq=1). Could you please let me know how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Comment: @ebrahimi it only makes a mistake when the input to `as.POSIXct` does not contain the information needed to resolve actual moment in time (i.e., in `UTC`). In [the question you linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156836/character-posixct-conversion-in-r-causes-wrong-timezone-values-on-daylight-savin), time zone information is correctly present in `time_seq_01` (verify with `as.numeric(time_seq_01)`); but is lost on conversion to `time_seq_02`.... (continued below)

Comment: Although we can see the difference with our eyes on the screen (e.g., "2012-10-28 02:00:00 CEST" vs. "2012-10-28 02:00:00 EST"), those time zone abbreviations are not used by `as.POSIXct`, and since they are ambiguous (cannot resolve "2012-10-28 02:00:00" as explained in Details in `?as.POSIXct`), the result OS-specific and unreliable.

Comment: So to prevent this issue when converting from POSIXct to character, use an output specification for timezone that is handled reliably by `as.POSIXct` (e.g., `format(time_seq_01, tz = "UTC")` or `format(time_seq_01, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z")`).

Answer (score 10):

If you'd like to do this in one line, recall that any `POSIXct` object in R is really just a number (seconds UTC since epoch beginning), and that the "timezone" is just an attribute that determines how that number is *printed*.

Therefore, we can use the `.POSIXct` helper function as follows:

```
x = as.POSIXct("2009-06-03 19:30", tz = "Europe/London")
.POSIXct(as.numeric(x), tz = 'America/Los_Angeles')
# [1] "2009-06-03 11:30:00 PDT"
```

`as.numeric` strips the class and attributes of `x`, and `.POSIXct` is shorthand for constructing a POSIXct object.

Note that I'm using `as.numeric()` and not `as.integer()` to avoid truncating milliseconds.

Comment: Just fixed a typo, and add origin to prevent error

x = as.POSIXct("2009-06-03 19:30", tz = "Europe/London")
x = as.POSIXct(as.integer(x), tz = 'America/Los_Angeles', origin = '1970-01-01')
x

Comment: @MichaelChirico but during daylight saving time, when we want to convert EST to UTC, it makes mistake? as it is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156836/character-posixct-conversion-in-r-causes-wrong-timezone-values-on-daylight-savin?noredirect=1&lq=1). Could you please let me know how to solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another, perhaps more clunky, way to do this is to create two new columns for "`date`" and "`time`" by extracting that information out of your "datetime" column and then combining those two columns into a new column and using POSIXct to choose the time zone you want the dates to be in.

```
#Extract the date and year from your "datetime" column to create two new columns.
data$date <- substr(data$datetime, 1, 10) #column for date (selects characters 1-10 from your "datetime" column and pastes them into the "year" column.
data$time <- substr(data$datetime, 12, 19) #column for year (same as above).
    
#Combine the two columns to create a new column "new.datetime" and select your timezone of choice.
data$new.datetime <- as.POSIXct(paste(data$year, data$time), format = 
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "America/Toronto").
    
#Confirm the timezone is in the proper format.
attr(data$new.datetime, "tzone")
[1] "America/Toronto"
```