# how-to convert a list of unix-time values to a time series class object

Tags: r, time-series

If I have a vector of unix timestamps, for example

```
> head(debug$time)
[1] 1.473639e+18 1.473639e+18 1.473639e+18 1.473639e+18 1.473640e+18
[6] 1.473640e+18
```

How can I use it as a `Date` vector in order to form a `ts` or `xts` object ?
I need this in order to parameterise and use the *bfast* library [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/bfast/bfast.pdf)

I tired to do the following (tz=CEST is not recognised btw):

```
t_ <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(debug$time), origin = '1970-01-01')
```

Could you please advise on this one ?

Comment: Where did those #'s come from? They're about 1,000,000,000 times too large.

Comment: @hrbrmstr is in microseconds (1/1,000,000 second). oops, you are right: 10^9 smaller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13160268/1457051) for a way around the CEST problem, but all you need to do is:

```
vals <- c(1.473639e+18, 1.473639e+18, 1.473639e+18, 1.473639e+18, 1.473640e+18, 1.473640e+18)
as.POSIXct(vals/1000000000, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00")
## [1] "2016-09-11 20:10:00 EDT" "2016-09-11 20:10:00 EDT" "2016-09-11 20:10:00 EDT" "2016-09-11 20:10:00 EDT" "2016-09-11 20:26:40 EDT"
## [6] "2016-09-11 20:26:40 EDT"
```

To make the date/time conversion work.

**UPDATE**

Looks like you can also do:

```
as.POSIXct(vals/1e9, origin="1970-01-01 00:00:00", tz="Etc/GMT+2")
```

to get your CEST working as well (from what I read, that's an equivalent time zone, but I don't live there or work with data from there so cannot validate that statement). Also using the scientific notation for Rich's sake :-)

Comment: `1e9` is 1000000000, but you know that ;) Fore!

Comment: aye. i kept both in long notation for effect. especially since that level of precision was not needed for these numbers. :-)