# Distinguish between daylight savings // lubridate::force_tz() output

Tags: r, lubridate

I want to distinguish between daylight savings in my time series data set. In the time zone `Europe/Berlin` every last sunday in october the clock gets rewind backwards from 3am back again to 2am. So in my data set are two 2am hours.

E.g. on `2016-10-30` the daylight saving ended on `02:00:00 CEST` such that the clock didn't proceed to the next hour of `03:00:00 CEST` but to `02:00:00 CET` and then to `03:00:00 CET`.

I don't understand why the console output of `force_tz()` function from the `lubridate` package doesn't show the forced time zone. But when I use `attributes()` the console lists the forced time zone as a `$tzone` attribute.

E.g.:

```
datetime = as.POSIXct("2016-10-30 02:00:00", tz = "Europe/Berlin")
datetime
[1] "2016-10-30 02:00:00 CEST"

# Now I want the 'same' datetime with CET time zone 
library(lubridate)
datetime.force <- force_tz(datetime, tz = "CET")
datetime.force
[1] "2016-10-30 02:00:00 CEST"

attributes(datetime.force)
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] "CET"
```

I want to understand why the console output doesn't show the `CET` time zone for the `datetime.force` variable.
And is it possible to use a `merge()` function which can distinguish between those two 2am with different time zones.

Thanks for your help and comments.

Comment: Quite similar issue plus solution (base R): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13156836/character-posixct-conversion-in-r-causes-wrong-timezone-values-on-daylight-savin