# Change timezone in a POSIXct object

Tags: r, datetime

Playing with dateTimes and timezone can be tricky in R.
Here is my question: I want to change the time-zone on a `POSIXct` object

```
R) data <- data.frame(x=c(1,2),dateTime=as.POSIXct(c("2010-03-11 03:30:00.432","2010-03-15 03:30:00.432"),format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",tz="America/Montreal"))
R) data
  x            dateTime
1 1 2010-03-11 03:30:00
2 2 2010-03-15 03:30:00
R) str(data)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ x       : num  1 2
 $ dateTime: POSIXct, format: "2010-03-11 03:30:00" "2010-03-15 03:30:00"
```

But if I want to change the timezone, the only thing I found is:

```
R) data$dateTime2 = format(data$dateTime,tz="Europe/Paris")
R) str(data)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x        : num  1 2
 $ dateTime : POSIXct, format: "2010-03-11 03:30:00" "2010-03-15 03:30:00"
 $ dateTime2: chr  "2010-03-11 09:30:00" "2010-03-15 08:30:00"
```

Or

```
R) data$dateTime2 = as.POSIXlt(data$dateTime,tz="Europe/Paris")
R) str(data)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x        : num  1 2
 $ dateTime : POSIXct, format: "2010-03-11 03:30:00" "2010-03-15 03:30:00"
 $ dateTime2: POSIXlt, format: "2010-03-11 09:30:00" "2010-03-15 08:30:00"
```

God (or somebody on SO) knows why it doesn't work with `POSIXct`

```
R) data$dateTime2 = as.POSIXct(data$dateTime,tz="Europe/Paris")
R) str(data)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x        : num  1 2
 $ dateTime : POSIXct, format: "2010-03-11 03:30:00" "2010-03-15 03:30:00"
 $ dateTime2: POSIXct, format: "2010-03-11 03:30:00" "2010-03-15 03:30:00"
```

Do I need to convert to `character` and cast back to `POSIXct` ?

Answer (score 83, accepted):

It doesn't work with `POSIXct` because `base::as.POSIXct.default` simply returns `x` if it's already `POSIXct`.  You can change the timezone via the `tzone` attribute:

```
attr(data$dateTime, "tzone") <- "Europe/Paris"
```

Comment: There is a setter function `indexTZ()` that does this too: `indexTZ(data$dateTime) <- "Europe/Paris"`

Comment: `.POSIXct(data$dateTime, tz="Europe/Paris")` also does it, but it's an .Internal function so it _probably_ shouldn't be used in a CRAN package.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel: that's to change the timezone of an xts object though, not a POSIXct object.

Comment: Aha!  POSIXct and POSIXlt objects have a 'tzone' attribute, and the downstream processes use it differently.

Comment: Note that if `dateTime` is a `data.table` column, you should use `setattr(data$dateTime, 'tzone', 'Europe/Paris')` since `attr<-` can inadvertently create copies of `data`

Answer (score 47):

In the `lubridate` package there is a function `with_tz` which changes the timezone attribute (effectively what Joshua described).

```
dttm <- as.POSIXct("2016-01-01 10:10:10", tz = "UTC")
dttm
[1] "2016-01-01 10:10:10 UTC"
```

Change timezone from `UTC` to `CET`

```
with_tz(dttm, "CET")
[1] "2016-01-01 11:10:10 CET"
```

Comment: `force_tz` is also a useful function in the `lubridate` package.  Useful when you read data from a file and the system assumes a certain timezone.  `force_tz` changes the time zone without changing the clock time.

Answer (score 2):

As of 7/23/2021. `indexTZ` is deprecated. `tzone` is good to use.

`tzone(data$dateTime) <- "Europe/Paris"`

Comment: It may be "deprecated" in the sense of being the older, original accessor function, but it is still the header on the help page, so when you attempt to find it with `??` you only see 'xts::indexTZ' on the results page. Or maybe it's only a soft deprecation? The help page does NOT say it's deprecated, but rather implies that "things will remain the same" with the exception of the addition of `tzone` and `tzone<-` functions