# as.POSIXct assigns different timezones

Tags: r, timezone, timestamp, posixct

I am importing a simple timestamp file with the structure `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"` , i.e. "2014-10-26 04:15:32". A sample data set:

`tz <- c("2014-10-26 00:27:14", "2014-10-26 00:42:14", "2014-10-26 00:57:14", 
"2014-10-26 01:12:14", "2014-10-26 01:27:14", "2014-10-26 01:42:14", 
"2014-10-26 01:57:14", "2014-10-26 02:00:32", "2014-10-26 02:12:14", 
"2014-10-26 02:15:32", "2014-10-26 02:27:14", "2014-10-26 02:30:32", 
"2014-10-26 02:42:14", "2014-10-26 02:45:32", "2014-10-26 02:57:14", 
"2014-10-26 03:00:32", "2014-10-26 03:15:32", "2014-10-26 03:30:32", 
"2014-10-26 03:45:32", "2014-10-26 04:00:32", "2014-10-26 04:15:32"
)`

Afterwards, I use
`tz <- as.POSIXct(tz, format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")` without assigning any timezone. However, when I display `tz` the output is the following:

`[1] "2014-10-26 00:27:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 00:42:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 00:57:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 01:12:14 CEST"
 [5] "2014-10-26 01:27:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 01:42:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 01:57:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 02:00:32 CEST"
 [9] "2014-10-26 02:12:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 02:15:32 CEST" "2014-10-26 02:27:14 CEST" "2014-10-26 02:30:32 CET" 
[13] "2014-10-26 02:42:14 CET"  "2014-10-26 02:45:32 CET"  "2014-10-26 02:57:14 CET"  "2014-10-26 03:00:32 CET" 
[17] "2014-10-26 03:15:32 CET"  "2014-10-26 03:30:32 CET"  "2014-10-26 03:45:32 CET"  "2014-10-26 04:00:32 CET" 
[21] "2014-10-26 04:15:32 CET"`

Any ideas why R assigns two different time zones - CEST and CET?
I changed my local settings to `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")` and I also used `Sys.setenv(TZ='CET')` but without any result. I used different ways of conversion described [Change timezone in a POSIXct object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141537/change-timezone-in-a-posixct-object) and http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2009/06/converting-time-zones.html but I am still not able to change the timezone to be only one. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh snap! The time changed exactly on 26th Oct and I have the same problem on 29th March where the time changed again. Any ideas how to avoid this?

Comment: What is your desired time zone that you wish to set?

Comment: CET or CEST, it doesn't really matter, I just want to keep it consistent through the whole dataset.

Comment: CET and CEST *are* the same time zone. What you see is daylight saving time.

Comment: Yes but some countries change to CEST and some don't. How can I handle this?

Comment: Then set the timezone to one that doesn't observe daylight saving time. You don't have to use your operating system's timezone. See `?timezone`.

Comment: @Boris - Use a named time zone, such as `'Europe/Paris'`

Comment: I tried using Europe/Paris but it's the same. I guess I have to choose a country which does not change the time. Thank you all!

Comment: I suppose you could use that strategy. Seems simpler to use the strategy in the answer to the duplicate question, though.