# r as.POSIXct get NA

Tags: r, time, na

Why did I get all NAs when converting timestamps below using as.POSIXct?

```
> head(tmp$timestamp_utc)
[1] Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015 Fri Jul 03 00:45:00 EDT 2015 Fri Jul 03 01:15:00 EDT 2015 Fri Jul 03 01:45:00 EDT 2015 Fri Jul 03 02:15:00 EDT 2015
[6] Fri Jul 03 02:45:00 EDT 2015
> tmp$timestamp_utc<- as.POSIXct(tmp$timestamp_utc, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S", tz="GMT")
> head(tmp$timestamp_utc)
[1] NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

UPDATE: 
        1. The initial problem is the format was wrong which was pointed out the some friends below. Correct format will not generate NA
        2. Then I find out EDT was not converted to GMT, though "GMT" is added in as.POSIXCT. Using with_tz solves this issue.

```
> as.POSIXct("Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y", tz="GMT")
[1] "2015-07-03 00:15:00 GMT"
> with_tz(as.POSIXct("Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y"),"GMT")
[1] "2015-07-03 04:15:00 GMT"
```

Comment: You get NA because you haven't specified the correct date format. For example, you don't have any /'s in your data.

Comment: Yeah, this is the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe this is the format you want:

`as.POSIXct("Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y", tz="GMT")`

Any to answer your specific question, and echo the comments, it didn't work because your format argument wasn't properly specified.

Edit: This is a little bit beyond the question originally asked, but you can convert the time based on changing time zone as follows (supporting question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141537/change-timezone-in-a-posixct-object)):

```
time <- "Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015"
format1 <- "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y"
time2 <- as.POSIXct(time, format=format1, tz="EST")
attr(time2, "tzone") <- "GMT"
time2
[1] "2015-07-03 05:15:00 GMT"
```

Comment: It works. Thanks. I was wondering the format is used for output format.

Comment: @user1047 I asked a related follow-up question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31821019/how-do-i-specify-posix-time-format-for-3-letter-tz-in-r)

Comment: BTW, why the code does not produce the time in GMT? "Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015" should be " 2015-07-03 04:15:00 GMT".  But as.POSIXct("Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015", format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S EDT %Y", tz="GMT") gave "2015-07-03 00:15:00 GMT", still 4 hours behind GMT.