# How do I specify POSIX (time) format for 3 letter tz in R, in order to ignore it?

Tags: r, timezone, posix, strptime

For output, the specification is `%Z` (see `?strptime`). But for input, how does that work?

To clarify, it'd be great for the time zone abbreviation to be parsed into useful information by `as.POSIXct()`, but more core to be question is how to get the function to at least ignore the time zone.

Here is my best workaround, but is there a particular format code to pass to `as.POSIXct()` that will work for all time zones?

```
times <- c("Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 EDT 2015", "Fri Jul 03 00:15:00 GMT 2015")
as.POSIXct(times, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y") # nope! strptime can't handle %Z in input

formats <- paste("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S", gsub(".+ ([A-Z]{3}) [0-9]{4}$", "\\1", times),"%Y")
as.POSIXct(times, format=formats) # works
```

Edit: Here is the output from the last line, as well as its class (from a separate call); the output is as expected. From the console:

```
> as.POSIXct(times, format=formats)
[1] "2015-07-03 00:15:00 EDT" "2015-07-03 00:15:00 EDT"

> attributes(as.POSIXct(times, format=formats))
$class
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt" 

$tzone
[1] ""
```

Comment: "%Z" is listed as "for output only". I don't think varying timezones are a supported input feature. I think you will need to extract the tz designator first and then supply it as an argument to the tz argument of as.POSIXct.You need to explain what you mean by "a particular format code to pass to as.POSIXct() that will work for all time zones". There is a `?timezone` help page.

Comment: @BondedDust Yep, I know it's output only, which is the basis for my question. I was hoping there would be a clever way of passing a regular expression to `format=`, something like `"[A-Z]{3}"` to account for any time zone. And you'll see that the second piece of code I have does solve the problem another way, using a regex, but it seemed like if you could specify the output, why not the input?

Comment: I also think you should check to see if your second effort was actually correct. Doesn't work properly (although did not throw an error) on my system and as I said before, I do not think that the tz argument accepts vectors of length greater than 1. Furthermore, "EDT" is not a recognized timezone. If it's recognized in your OS, then I still think an `mapply` solution may be needed.

Comment: @BondedDust I'm not specifying the tz argument. I edited my answer to show that the code does produce the desired output.

Comment: So you were expecting the "GMT" tz to be ignored and interpreted as "EDT"?

Comment: @BondedDust You make a really good point here. I generally work with minute-to-minute data, using dates to split up data sets and times to order them and make sure there aren't gaps. So for my typical use case, I don't care what time zone the date is in. But others very likely may!

Comment: To be clear, you want to specify `%Z` field as input to strptime purely in order to ignore it in your input strings, since it comes before `%Y`.

Comment: @smci Yes, I believe so (it's been a while)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is, "no, you can't."  Those are abbreviations and they are not guaranteed to uniquely identify a specific timezone.

For example, is "EST" Eastern Standard Time in the US or Australia? Is "CST" Central Standard Time in the US or Australia, or is it China Standard Time, or is it Cuba Standard Time?

---

I just noticed that you're not trying to parse the timezone abbreviation, you are simply trying to avoid it. I don't know of a way to tell `strptime` to ignore arbitrary characters. I do know that it will ignore anything in the character representation of the time after the end of the format string. For example:

```
R> # The year is not parsed, so the current year is used
R> as.POSIXct(times, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S")
[1] "2015-07-03 00:15:00 UTC" "2015-07-03 00:15:00 UTC"
```

Other than that, a regular expression is the only thing I can think of that solves this problem. Unlike your example, I would use the regex on the input character vector to remove all 3-5 character timezone abbreviations.

```
R> times_no_tz <- gsub(" [[:upper:]]{3,5} ", " ", times)
R> as.POSIXct(times_no_tz, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
[1] "2015-07-03 00:15:00 UTC" "2015-07-03 00:15:00 UTC"
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, but some of those symbols already locale- specific interpretations, right? More generally, when I tried to solve this problem originally, I was surprised that the function didn't do some sort of wildcard or regex, if asked. You can insert any set of *known* characters or punctuation, and the function still knows how to convert the relevant information into a time. I'm just asking it to ignore 3 letters (if it can use them, that'd be great)

Comment: @rbatt: I believe the abbreviations are specific to the timezone database, not the locale. And I don't know of a way to tell `strptime` to ignore arbitrary characters. I do know that it will ignore anything in the character representation of the time after the end of the format string (i.e. format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S" works and sets the year to the current year).

Comment: Nice, I did not know it would ignore the ending ... that doesn't get me there for this particular situation, but that's definitely useful information.

Comment: For what it's worth, I believe that `strptime` is just a wrapper around system libraries (`man 3 strptime` on my system), so limitations/weirdness are not R's fault ... until someone comes up with a spectacular cross-platform general-purpose time conversion library, it's all going to be workarounds ...

Comment: @BenBolker Fair points, for sure. I'm just so used to thinking a workaround is the only way I can do something, to later learn that others know of a 10x improvement. So it sounds like 1) I probably won't be able to make use of the 3 letter time zone; 2) to drop the 3 letter time zone, I have to hope it's at the end or regex it out.