# R date origin for time in seconds

Tags: r, datetime, hdf5, rhdf5

I daily have a time series in seconds since the job start (00:00h UTC). As I want to plot time series of other data, I want convert time series in seconds to dates. All data comes from a hdf5 file read with package rhdf5

```
>tiempo=h5read("rams2.h5","t_coords")
> class(tiempo)
[1] "array"
> head(tiempo)
[1]    0 1800 3600 5400 7200 9000
```

Then I have tried and as.POSIXct to build a dataframe (to later use with ggplot2).

```
> temps<-as.data.frame(as.POSIXct(tiempo, origin = "1960-01-01 00:00"))
> class(temps)
[1] "data.frame"
> head(temps)
  as.POSIXct(tiempo, origin = "1960-01-01 00:00")
1                             1960-01-01 01:00:00
2                             1960-01-01 01:30:00
3                             1960-01-01 02:00:00
4                             1960-01-01 02:30:00
5                             1960-01-01 03:00:00
6                             1960-01-01 03:30:00
```

The problem comes fromt the first value of "temps"

> 1                             1960-01-01 01:00:00

but it should be 1960-01-01 00:00:00 as this is the supplied origin and first value of "tiempo" is 0. It seems that an hour has been added to every time.

Maybe I'm missing something when setting origin? Or while reading h5 file? Any idea?

Thanks in advance

PD: I can't supply example data as the h5 file is a very huge one.

**CORRECT CODE**
Thanks to ottlngr answer and Richard Telford comment, the problem was a time zone issue solved by adding tz= "UTC"

```
temps<-as.data.frame(as.POSIXct(tiempo, origin = "1960-01-01 00:00:00",tz = "UTC"))
```

Comment: I would like to receive comments from the downvotes so I could improve the question, thanks.

Comment: Probably a timezone problem: `as.POSIXct(1, origin = "1960-01-01 00:00", tz = "UTC")` gives midnight (which would be 1am CET)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly you should use the `tz` argument in `as.POSIXct()`, but **hard to tell without sample data**. Take a look at this question, it might help you: [Change timezone in a POSIXct object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141537/change-timezone-in-a-posixct-object)