# Having Issue Converting Time Zone of POSIXct and then extracting Date / Time separately

Tags: r, timezone, lubridate

My reproducible example below is based in part on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141537/change-timezone-in-a-posixct-object) of changing time zones in R.

I am struggling to extract the correct (EST) date and time out of a POSIXct column that is in UTC time zone. Please see my quick example on this:

```
> dput(mydf)
structure(list(scheduled = structure(c(1541525400, 1541538000, 
1541545200, 1541545500, 1541547000, 1541547000, 1541547000, 1541547000, 
1541547000, 1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800, 
1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800, 1541548800
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), homePoints = c(110L, 
82L, 77L, 102L, 76L, 104L, 89L, 84L, 77L, 97L, 71L, 114L, 91L, 
105L, 74L, 100L, 74L, 102L, 68L, 89L), awayPoints = c(54L, 67L, 
67L, 82L, 55L, 55L, 49L, 70L, 67L, 63L, 72L, 39L, 52L, 55L, 77L, 
80L, 66L, 48L, 75L, 76L)), row.names = c(NA, 20L), class = "data.frame")

> mydf
             scheduled homePoints awayPoints
1  2018-11-06 17:30:00        110         54
2  2018-11-06 21:00:00         82         67
3  2018-11-06 23:00:00         77         67
4  2018-11-06 23:05:00        102         82
5  2018-11-06 23:30:00         76         55
6  2018-11-06 23:30:00        104         55
7  2018-11-06 23:30:00         89         49
8  2018-11-06 23:30:00         84         70
9  2018-11-06 23:30:00         77         67
10 2018-11-07 00:00:00         97         63
11 2018-11-07 00:00:00         71         72
12 2018-11-07 00:00:00        114         39
13 2018-11-07 00:00:00         91         52
14 2018-11-07 00:00:00        105         55
15 2018-11-07 00:00:00         74         77
16 2018-11-07 00:00:00        100         80
17 2018-11-07 00:00:00         74         66
18 2018-11-07 00:00:00        102         48
19 2018-11-07 00:00:00         68         75
20 2018-11-07 00:00:00         89         76
```

Things go wrong when I attempt to (1st) change the time zone of the `scheduled` column, and then try to create separate `gameDate` and `gameTime` columns:

```
> attr(mydf$scheduled, "tzone")
[1] "UTC"
> attr(mydf$scheduled, "tzone") <- "EST"
> attr(mydf$scheduled, "tzone")
[1] "EST"
> head(mydf)
            scheduled homePoints awayPoints
1 2018-11-06 12:30:00        110         54
2 2018-11-06 16:00:00         82         67
3 2018-11-06 18:00:00         77         67
4 2018-11-06 18:05:00        102         82
5 2018-11-06 18:30:00         76         55
6 2018-11-06 18:30:00        104         55

mydf <- mydf %>%
  dplyr::mutate(gameDate = as.Date(scheduled)) %>%
  dplyr::mutate(gameTime = strftime(scheduled, format="%H:%M:%S"))

> head(mydf, 12)
             scheduled homePoints awayPoints   gameDate gameTime
1  2018-11-06 12:30:00        110         54 2018-11-06 17:30:00
2  2018-11-06 16:00:00         82         67 2018-11-06 21:00:00
3  2018-11-06 18:00:00         77         67 2018-11-06 23:00:00
4  2018-11-06 18:05:00        102         82 2018-11-06 23:05:00
5  2018-11-06 18:30:00         76         55 2018-11-06 23:30:00
6  2018-11-06 18:30:00        104         55 2018-11-06 23:30:00
7  2018-11-06 18:30:00         89         49 2018-11-06 23:30:00
8  2018-11-06 18:30:00         84         70 2018-11-06 23:30:00
9  2018-11-06 18:30:00         77         67 2018-11-06 23:30:00
10 2018-11-06 19:00:00         97         63 2018-11-07 00:00:00
11 2018-11-06 19:00:00         71         72 2018-11-07 00:00:00
12 2018-11-06 19:00:00        114         39 2018-11-07 00:00:00
```

... uh oh, these dates and times aren't right (all times wrong, rows 10-20 for date also wrong).

Unfortunately, I cannot use the same approach of using (attr) to change these new columns:

```
> attr(mydf$gameDate, "tzone") <- "EST"
> attr(mydf$gameTime, "tzone") <- "EST"
> head(mydf)
             scheduled homePoints awayPoints   gameDate gameTime
1  2018-11-06 12:30:00        110         54 2018-11-06 17:30:00
2  2018-11-06 16:00:00         82         67 2018-11-06 21:00:00
3  2018-11-06 18:00:00         77         67 2018-11-06 23:00:00
4  2018-11-06 18:05:00        102         82 2018-11-06 23:05:00
5  2018-11-06 18:30:00         76         55 2018-11-06 23:30:00
6  2018-11-06 18:30:00        104         55 2018-11-06 23:30:00
```

... this didnt help.

Any thoughts / help on how I can get the **correct (EST) date and times** out of this POSIXct column would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't use `"EST"`.  Use `"America/New_York"`

Comment: is there somewhere that I can see a full list of time zones?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones

Comment: [`?OlsonNames`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/timezones.html) (it returns a vector of 592 world-wide time zone names).