# Something wrong in convert ISO 8601 date/times with a 'POSIXct' object

Tags: r

There is something I don't understand. I simply try to convert a date in an other time zone. The date is in the 8601-ISO format. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395117/how-do-you-convert-dates-times-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-r).

```
pb.txt <- "2012-09-11T21:23:20Z"
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, tz="UTC")
format(pb.date, tz="WEST",usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2012-09-11 WEST"
```

Why only the date appears and not anymore the timestamp ? 
I tried also :

```
pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, origin=ISOdatetime(2012,09,11,21,23,20))
format(pb.date, tz="WEST",usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2012-09-10 22:00:00 WEST
```

It's better, but the timestamp is rounded. How to convert perfectly an 8601-ISO datetime ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the correct format:

```
as.POSIXct(pb.txt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
[1] "2012-09-11 21:23:20 UTC"
```

Comment: Ok, I get the same result : converting the date in POSIXct is ok. But print it in another time zone doesn'work : format(pb.date, tz="WEST",usetz=TRUE) >> [1] "2012-09-10 22:00:00 WEST". Nothing changes.

Comment: @jonathan: `"WEST"` isn't a valid timezone.  See `?timezone`.

Comment: Yes, you're right about that (as plannapus noticed it too). It's not one but two mistakes I've made ! Thanks very much for helping. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @JoshuaUlrich answer, don't use daylight saving time timezone: use regular time zone, the system will convert automatically if the day chosen falls during summer time.

Given `pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")` as per Joshua's answer, this fails:

```
format(pb.date, tz="WEST",usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2012-09-11 21:23:20 UTC"
```

but this doesn't:

```
format(pb.date, tz="WET", usetz=TRUE)
[1] "2012-09-11 22:23:20 WEST"
```

Comment: What I get is : > format(pb.date, tz="WET",usetz=TRUE) >> [1] "2012-09-10 23:00:00 WEST" and > format(pb.date, tz="WEST",usetz=TRUE) >> [1] "2012-09-10 22:00:00 WEST" So, nothing changes... :/

Comment: You did literally `pb.txt <- "2012-09-11T21:23:20Z"` followed by `pb.date <- as.POSIXct(pb.txt, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")` and then `format(pb.date, tz="WET", usetz=TRUE)` gives you "2012-09-10 23:00:00 WEST"?

Comment: You're right, it was weird. It seems that I've not correctly done something... I've checked today... and everything works great. Thanks very much. :)