# Interconverting POSIXct and numeric in R

Tags: r, excel, date, time, posixct

I'm importing data from Excel and then trying to manipulate dates and times in R and it's giving me SUCH A HEADACHE. In the Excel file, one column contained a date and time, and another column contained a different time for that same day. The data in R looks basically like this example:

```
 mydata <- data.frame(DateTime1 = as.POSIXct(c("2014-12-13 04:56:00",
                                         "2014-12-13 09:30:00",
                                         "2014-12-13 11:30:00",
                                         "2014-12-13 13:30:00"),
                                       origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT"),
                      Time2 = c(0.209, 0.209, 0.715, 0.715))
```

I'd like to have a new column in POSIXct format with the date and the 2nd time, and I can't get that to work. I've tried:

```
 mydata$DateTime2 <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.Date(mydata$DateTime1)
                            + mydata$Time2), origin = "1970-01-01",
                           tz = "GMT")
```

but that gives me dates and times close to 1/1/1970.

This is more convoluted, but one thing that has worked in other similiar situations that I've also tried is:

```
 library(lubridate)
 mydata$DateTime2 <- ymd_hms(format(as.POSIXct(as.Date(mydata$DateTime1) + 
                                                mydata$Time2,
                      origin = "1899-12-30", tz = "GMT")))
```

but that gives me dates and times that are off by 8 hours. That time difference makes me think that the problem is the time zone since I'm on Pacific Standard Time, but I *set* it to GMT both in the input data and when trying to convert! What gives? I'm hesitant to just add 8 hours to everything because of daylight savings time complications.

Really, both of the attempts I'm listing here seem to have problems with interconversion, i.e., if you start with a POSIXct object and convert it to numeric and then convert it back again to POSIXct, you should end up back where you started and you *don't*. Similarly, if you start with the time zone being GMT and then you add something that also is set to have the time zone as GMT, then you shouldn't have a problem with things somewhere mysteriously getting converted to the system time zone.

Advice?

Comment: Examine `unclass(DateTime1)` before and after converting. It should be the same underlying integers (technically `numeric`) before and after. If that's so, it's just a matter of setting the right time zone/origin.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I'm not seeing any difference between including `unclass(...` and not including it.

Comment: I may be misunderstanding, but why couldn't you just directly add `Time2` to `DateTime1`. I'm not sure of the units of `Time2`, but let's say it's days, just for illustration. Then, `mydata$DateTime2 = mydata$DateTime1 + mydata$Time2*24*60*60` (because POSIXct is in seconds, so we convert `Time2` to seconds).

Comment: The problem is that I'm not adding the second clock time to the first. Instead, I need the date and only the date in DateTime1 and then I need to add to that the clock time in Time2.

Comment: Ah, okay. But then why does `Time2` look like a decimal number rather than a time?

Comment: When I import it from Excel, it's automatically converted to numeric class, so it looks like a decimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer based on chris holbrook's answer here: [How do you convert dates/times from one time zone to another in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395117/how-do-you-convert-dates-times-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-r)

This worked:

```
 mydata$DateTime2 <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(mydata$DateTime1) +
                                 mydata$Time2)
 attributes(mydata$DateTime2)$tzone <- "GMT"
```

@MichaelChirico and I were correct that the time zone was the problem. I'm still not sure why, but the time zone for DateTime2 was apparently PST. It didn't *list* "PST" when I checked `str(mydata$DateTime2)`, but based on the time difference, it must have been, in fact, PST until I set the attributes. Crazy. It did that even though DateTime1 was GMT.