# tibble starting time in R

Tags: r, time, tibble, posixct

I run the code below

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
xx1<-'20211222000010'
start_time <- strptime(xx1, format = "%Y%m%d%H%M%S")

wqdata_A <- tibble(time = as.POSIXct(10*((1:(1*8640))-1), origin = start_time))
```

`20211222000010`means `December 22nd, 2021, 00:00:10` .

I expected that `wqdata_A` would give me the series of time starting from
`2021-12-22 00:00:10`because I set the origin as `start_time`.
However, when I run the code, the starting time of `wqdata_A` is `2021-12-22 09:00:10`.
I don't know why the starting time changes even though I set the origin using `tibble`.

Comment: I'm going to guess it's a timezone issue.  Are you, by any chance, located in a timezone which is GMT + 9?  POSIXct always uses GMT as the time zone.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395117/how-do-you-convert-dates-times-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-r) may suggest some solutions.

Comment: I'm in South Korea. `start_time` gives `"2021-12-22 00:00:10 KST"` .

Comment: Exactly!  KST is GMT + 9.  You're providing `asPOSIXct()` with a datetime without a timezone.  So it assumes GMT.  But your tibble is printed using your locale, which is GMT + 9.  R has NOT changed your starting time.  Dealing with dates and times is not straightforward!  My link above gives you your answer: provide a timezone when creating your sequewnce of datetimes.

Comment: Yeah! You're right. When I changed a timezone, it worked !