# Converting UTC to CET. using base R

Tags: r, datetime

I am trying to convert `'2023-02-04 01:00:00 UTC'` to `UTC+2`.

```
# create UTC date
utc_date <- as.POSIXct(
  x = '2023-02-04 01:00:00',
  tz = 'UTC',
  usetz = TRUE
)

# convert date
format(
  utc_date,
  format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M',
  tz = Sys.timezone(),
  usetz = TRUE
  )
```

My `Sys.timezone()` is `"Europe/Copenhagen"` and I was expecting the output to be `"2023-02-04 03:00 CET"`, but its currently shows `"2023-02-04 02:00 CET"`

What am I  missing here? Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as expected. Standard Danish time is UTC+1 and not UTC+2. You are probably being tricked by daylight savings time (DST) which is indeed UTC+2. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_the_Danish_Realm

---

If you want to convert your UTC datetime to a string with UTC+2, you could use `strftime`.

```
strftime(utc_date, tx = "UTC+2")

#> "2023-02-04 02:00:00"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. However, if I use the answer found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395117/how-do-you-convert-dates-times-from-one-time-zone-to-another-in-r

I get the expected result. I was hoping that there were a solution, that didn't include directly editing the attributes.